# OSX 10.6 "make" command not working

Tags: xcode, macos, perl, makefile, cpan

I've worked on this problem for a few days and couldn't find any solution even after reading several other blogs.

Whenever I try to install modules using CPAN, these installs fail since 'make' errors.

```
cpan[1]> install Clone                                                          
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.18)
Reading '/Users/erikhanschen/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 11 Jun 2014 12:06:12 GMT
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.92)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9711)
Reading 49 yaml files from /Users/erikhanschen/.cpan/build/
DONE
Restored the state of none (in 1.7859 secs)
Running install for module 'Clone'
  GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /Users/erikhanschen/.cpan/build/Clone-0.37-F3R5u0
  GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error

CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.120351)

cpan[2]>
```

After I had to replaced my hard drive recently, I had to re-install Xcode but even after that, the make command didn't work. Uninstalling Xcode and installing GCC compiler instead didn't help. `make` is in `/usr/bin/` and that directory is in my PATH, and make and GCC run when run without arguments, but the CPAN installer still can't find it when I'm trying to install a module.

After removing the contents of the CPAN build directory, trying to install a module still crashes at "make".

```
    cpan[2]> install Clone                                                                                                                               
    Running install for module 'Clone'
    CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.45)
    CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.008)
    Checksum for /Users/erikhanschen/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GA/GARU/Clone-        0.37.tar.gz ok
    Scanning cache /Users/erikhanschen/.cpan/build for sizes
    DONE
    CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.96)
    x Clone-0.37/
    x Clone-0.37/Changes
    x Clone-0.37/Clone.pm
    x Clone-0.37/Clone.xs
    x Clone-0.37/Makefile.PL
    x Clone-0.37/MANIFEST
    x Clone-0.37/META.json
    x Clone-0.37/META.yml
    x Clone-0.37/README
    x Clone-0.37/t/
    x Clone-0.37/t/01array.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/02hash.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/03scalar.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/04tie.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/05dtype.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/06refcnt.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/07magic.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/08fieldhash.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/dclone.t
    x Clone-0.37/t/dump.pl
    x Clone-0.37/t/tied.pl
    CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
    CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.13)
    Configuring G/GA/GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
    Checking if your kit is complete...
    Looks good
    'EXPATINCPATH' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.
    'EXPATLIBPATH' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.
    Generating a Unix-style Makefile
    Writing Makefile for Clone
    Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
      GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz
      /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL EXPATLIBPATH=/non-standard/lib EXPATINCPATH=/non-standard/include -- OK
    Running make for G/GA/GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz
    cp Clone.pm blib/lib/Clone.pm
    AutoSplitting blib/lib/Clone.pm (blib/lib/auto/Clone)
    Running Mkbootstrap for Clone ()
    chmod 644 Clone.bs
    /usr/bin/perl /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap  /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/ExtUtils/typemap  Clone.xs > Clone.xsc && mv Clone.xsc Clone.c
    gcc-4.2 -c   -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include -O3   -DVERSION=\"0.37\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.37\"  "-        I/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   Clone.c
    /usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for        architecture ppc not installed
    Installed assemblers are:
    /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
    /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc23LjqR.out (No such file or directory)
    make: *** [Clone.o] Error 2
      GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz
      /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
    Failed during this command:
     GARU/Clone-0.37.tar.gz                       : make NO
```

I've already updated perl, CPAN, and Module::Build. I'm thinking the next step is to upgrade to 10.7, 10.8, or 10.9 and try to reinstall Command Line Tools straight from Apple.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the output of `make --version`?

Comment: $ make --version

GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin10.0

Comment: Try removing the contents of the CPAN `build` directory and start over.  What happens then?  You should at the very least get a more specific error.

Comment: Where would I find the CPAN build directory and can I just rm those contents? What do you mean start over- reinstall CPAN again or try and install a module?

Comment: `rm -rf $HOME/.cpan/build/*`.  Try to install the same module and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 2):

> I had to re-install Xcode but even after that, the make command didn't work...

Install Command Line tools. Open Xcode, and then go to ***Xcode → Preferences → Downloads***.